# Android StudioでGoogle cloud Moduleを追加したい

Tags: android-studio

お世話になります
AndroidStudioでGoogleCloudModuleを自分のアプリに追加したいと思っているのですが、
自分のAndroidStudioにはそれがないっぽいのですが。。。
https://cloud.google.com/mobile/app_engine/add_module
ここを見てやってます

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387225/google-cloud-module-option-is-not-visible-in-android-studio-1-0-0/27425795#27425795
step3,4を見ろと書いてあるのですが、そもそも添付の形なので、見当たらないのですが。。。

これはどうしたらよいのでしょうか

よろしくお願いします。[image: Add Module]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

情けないことに自己解決しました。
AndroidStudioのPreferncesからPluginを追加すればいいだけでした。
失礼いたしました